# Close MATLAB GUI with a dialog

Tags: matlab, user-interface, button, matlab-guide

I'm doing a GUI with GUIDE and want to close the figure with a dialog.

I have a button with this

```
selection = questdlg('Close This Figure?',...
      'Close Request Function',...
      'Yes','No','Yes'); 
   switch selection, 
      case 'Yes',
         delete(gcf)
      case 'No'
      return 
   end
```

and it works fine but I want the [main button](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTke51JO82bgpgGrpcgjMNKHZF00b5z8JaAckTS6LE684AcqjHbZw) to do the same thing.

I tryed to put this next to

```
function varargout = file_name(varargin)
...
```

but won't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use above code in a function say:

```
%Save in myclose_callback.m

function myclose_callback(src,evnt)
selection = questdlg('Close This Figure?',...
      'Close Request Function',...
      'Yes','No','Yes'); 
   switch selection, 
      case 'Yes',
         delete(gcf)
      case 'No'
      return 
   end
end
```

Then use:

```
%From other .m script or from command window
figure('CloseRequestFcn',@myclose_callback)
```

To make this as your default callback for all figures, use:

`set(0,'DefaultFigureCloseRequestFcn',@myclose_callback)`

Comment: First I tryed your first code and gave me an error. where should I put this code or call the function?

Comment: and `figure('CloseRequestFcn',@myclose_callback)` ? In the beggining of my main *.m file?

Comment: It didn't work, I putted in the end but nothing happens. I want that this dialog appears every time I close my figure...

Comment: @mafap Updated and follow, it works for me when I hit 'X' button.

Comment: If I put this in the end it is associated with some Callback function. and very time I want to call this function I have to put figure('CloseRequestFcn',@myclose_callback) ?

Comment: problem solved: GUIDE > View Callback > CloseRequestFcn > paste my code